# What is difference between database engine and database driver

Tags: mysql, database

what is difference between database ,database engine database driver
database drivers are used to connect with database , any kind of database but then what are the engines

Comment: [Is asking on Stack Overflow really your last resort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: I have updated your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What is the database?

A database is an organized collection of structured information or data, usually stored electronically in a computer system. Typically, a database is controlled by a database management system (DBMS). Together, the data and the DBMS, along with the applications associated with it, are called a database system, usually shortened to simply database.

The data in the most common types of databases in operation today are typically used as row and column structures in a series of tables to increase the efficiency of data processing and querying. Thus, data can be easily accessed, managed, modified, updated, monitored and organized. Most databases use a structured query language (SQL) to write and query data.

## What is the database engine?

The Database Engines are specific programs, dedicated to serve as intermediaries between the databases and the applications that use them as main function, each one of them fulfills a specific task, ranging from creating the database to manage the use and access to it.

## What is the database database controller?

A database driver is software that allows you to talk to your database from your application. There are language specific drivers such as JDBC, ODBC, OLE DB where the driver interface is implemented according to the language specifications so that your application can interact with the database according to the predefined specifications.

There are two types of storage engines in MySQL and MariaDB: transactional and non-transactional.

For MySQL 5.5 and later, the default storage engine is InnoDB. The default storage engine for MySQL before 5.5 was MyISAM. Choosing the right storage engine is an important strategic decision that will affect future development. In this post, we will use MyISAM, InnoDB, Memory and CSV storage engines. If you are new to MySQL and are studying the MySQL and MariaDB database management system, this is an important topic. If you are planning a production database, things get more complex.

#### List of storage engines

- **InnoDB :** is the most widely used storage engine with transaction support. It is an ACID compliant storage engine. It supports row-level locking, failover and multi-version concurrency control. It is the only engine that provides a foreign key referential integrity constraint. Oracle recommends using InnoDB for tables, except for specialized use cases.
- **MyISAM :** is the original storage engine. It is a fast storage engine. It does not support transactions. MyISAM provides table-level locking. It is mainly used in Web and data warehousing.
- **Memory :** creates tables in memory (hence the name). It is the fastest engine. Provides table-level locking. It does not support transactions. Memory storage engine is ideal for creating temporary tables or quick lookups. Data is lost when the database is restarted.
- **CSV :** stores data in CSV files. It provides great flexibility because data in this format is easily integrated into other applications.
- **Merge :** operates on underlying MyISAM tables. Merge tables help manage large volumes of data more easily. It logically groups a number of identical MyISAM tables and references them as a single object. It is a good choice for data warehousing environments.
- **The Archive** : storage engine is optimized for high-speed insertion. It compresses data as it is inserted. It does not support transactions. It is ideal for storing and retrieving large amounts of archived historical data that is rarely referenced.
- **The Blackhole :** storage engine accepts but does not store data. Fetches always return an empty set. The functionality can be used in distributed database design where data is automatically replicated, but not stored locally. This storage engine can be used for performance testing among others.
- **The Federated :** storage engine provides the ability to separate MySQL servers to create a logical database from many physical servers. Queries on the local server are automatically executed on the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored in the local tables. Good for distributed environments

#### From the administration console we can list the available storage engines :

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINES\G
*************************** 1. ROW ***************************
      Engine: InnoDB
     Support: DEFAULT
     Comment: Supports transactions, row-level locking, AND FOREIGN KEYS
Transactions: YES
          XA: YES
  Savepoints: YES
*************************** 2. ROW ***************************
      Engine: CSV
     Support: YES
     Comment: CSV storage engine
Transactions: NO
          XA: NO
  Savepoints: NO
...
```

#### Specify and modify storage engines

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(50), 
    -> Cost INTEGER) ENGINE='MyISAM';
```

OR

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Cars ENGINE='MyISAM';
```